# SQL divide by shifted value of other field

Tags: sql, shift, dbt

I have a table that looks like this:
[image]

Where RETENTION is the division of N_CUSTOMERS by CUSTOMER_WHEN_0 for each PERIOD_NUMBER.

Now I need to get another new field that is the result of dividing each retention value of thar PERIOD_NUMBER by the retetion value of the previous PERIOUD_NUMBER. In the example of the image it's not appreciated, but I have all the consecutive values for PERIOD_NUMBER. When the PERIOD_NUMBER is 0, it doesn't matter that the division by its shifter value is NAN or similar, I will replace it later.

So, summarizing, my desired output is a ner field that shows the result of dividing the RETENTION value of the PERIOD_NUMBER of that row by the RETENTION value of the previous PERIOD_NUMBER. I'm using DBT and in case is useful I have the querys I used to get these fields and I have the code to do that process in Python, but I need to do it in SQL

first purchase of the user, ORDER_MONTH is the date  of that purchase, and PERIOD_NUMBER is the date difference in months between COHORT and ORDER_MONTH. N_CUSTOMERS is the number of customers in each PERIOD_NUMBER in each COHORT, and CUSTOMER_WHEN_0 is the number of users in each cohort when the PERIOD_NUMBER is 0.
I had to use a window function in order to achive this last field.

Comment: You have no indication of the cohort in your sample data, which makes the question quite hard to understand.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Thanks for the answer, I omitted it as it's just a conceptual aclaration but the data is already grouped by cohort so is not necessary to take it into account. Sorry if that made it hard to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can get the previous RETENTION using a subquery, assuming that the period numbers are all consecutive:

```
SELECT
    N_CUSTOMERS,
    PERIOD_NUMBER,
    CUSTOMER_WHEN_0,
    RETENTION,
    (SELECT st_inner.RETENTION
        FROM sourcetable st_inner
        WHERE st_inner.PERIOD_NUMBER = st_outer.PERIOD_NUMBER - 1
    ) as PREVIOUS_RETENTION
FROM sourcetable st_outer
```

I left out the calculation for readability's sake, but I think it should be clear how to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much Neal, thanks to this query I have been able to solve it, really helpful!!